# FixtureReplacement with Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, fixtures

I am using Cucumber with Selenium, FixtureReplacement and DatabaseCleaner.

Funnily enough, my data I created with FixtureReplacement is not accessible from my tests.

I have added an own rails environment for selenium and I am using an own profile for my enhanced selenium features.
My cucumber setup for the selenium profile is:

```
Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :selenium
  config.application_environment = :selenium
end

Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false

require "database_cleaner"

# Clean the database once when starting
DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  include FixtureReplacement
end

After do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

# this is necessary to have webrat "wait_for" the response body to be available
# when writing steps that match against the response body returned by selenium
World(Webrat::Selenium::Matchers)
```

FixtureReplacement works well, I have tested it in the Rails console.

I am running my selenium features with:

```
RAILS_ENV=selenium cucumber -p selenium features/enhanced/test.feature
```

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried Cucumber with Watir? http://www.vimeo.com/2871256

Comment: You say FixtureReplacement works in the Rails console, but is that in your test environment or in your selenium environment.  My first guess would be that FixtureReplacement is only loading in test, and not in selenium.  But I don't know anything about FixtureReplacement.

Comment: FixtureReplacement is a Rails plugin, so it will be loaded in every environment.

Additionally, I had a look on its source code and there were no limitations to the test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had nothing to do with Fixtures. I thought I cannot access my data, because I couldn't login.

The following fixed it:
[Cucumber + selenium fails randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966052/cucumber-selenium-fails-randomly/966998#966998)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you are using Database Cleaner correctly? In my env.rb, I am using it like this:

```
Before do
  require 'database_cleaner'
  require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

This works for me when using Factory Girl.

Comment: This also does not work for me. Can you post your whole Cucumber setup?

Comment: BTW, I have changed to Factory Girl.

Comment: Here's a gist: http://gist.github.com/215924

Basically:

* Run features in the test env (perhapsnot a great idea)
* Turn off transactional fixtures 
* Configure Webrat to use selenium (with a few additional config options specific to my setup) 
* Require Factory Girl (perhaps the bit you are missing?)
* Define Database cleaner in a Before hook.

Hope that helps, 

Ad.